# Is there a way to cleanly handle org-mode latex exports across regional domains?

Tags: emacs, unicode, latex, org-mode, cjk

Specifically, I'm looking for something that will bridge the English-Japanese problem: Japanese is most easily and quickly output with `platex %b` and `dvipdf %b.dvi`, which uses pLaTeX (specifically for Japanese text), but this breaks English PDF outputs that work using the default `org-process-as-pdf` variable (which uses `pdflatex`). Is there a way to define this per-file, or modify the exporter interface to separate these without rewriting a huge portion of it? I'm on org-mode 7.9.3 right now but will migrate probably by February.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use XeLaTeX. The following general process should cover most every base:

```
xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f
biber %b # or bibtex, or your favorite bibliography handler
xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f
xelatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f
```

Additionally, you will need the following headers in the org file:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{xeCJK}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setCJKmainfont{TakaoExMincho} % for \rmfamily
```

I tested this on a full document including all kinds of embeddings and links, and it *just worked.*